# A notification of changes system for an ASP.NET web application using SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, notifications

For our intranet site, we want to begin including visual flags on buttons that lead to sections where content has changed that the user hasn't viewed yet.

All I can think of to achieve this is, on each Page_Load, do a query to compare the user's last access date against the content of that section to see if anything new has been added since the last visit.

For example, we have a "news" page.  The URL is news.aspx, and the button to reach that page says "News".  Our News table has a DateCreated column that indicates when an article was posted.  So first we get the datetime of the user's last access to news.aspx.  We have a table called PageAccessLogs with just three simple columns: username, url, and accessedtime.  First we would query PageAccessLogs to find out the last time that user has accessed news.aspx.  Let's say the result of that is 2012-11-06 10:34:25.  Then find out how many articles were posted AFTER 2012-11-06 10:34:25.  If there is 1 article between that time and now, display a red "1" above the News button.  If there are 2 articles between that time and now, display a red "2" above the News button.  And so on.

I haven't implemented it yet, but I'm pretty sure the above will work.  With my limited knowledge, I can't think of any other ways to achieve my goal, other than just running that query on every Page_Load for every user.  Is this the common approach?  Is there a method to achieve the same goal, without necessarily querying the server on every Page_Load?

I thought maybe there might be some kind of trick to use cookies to store last access dates, but even with that approach the server needs to be queried to see if there are new articles since the last update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider an additional column "seen" defaults to false as new content is loaded it is assumed to be unseen and when a user reads it / displays it update for that column is done to ark it as read. That way no messy time stamp issues. Also removes the need to do anything specific about recalculating read / unread